# map is not a function cannot fetch data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an issue fetching data from api, when map through my array of data i am getting error message that map is not function. I have fetched the data on the index page then passed it as props to the coinlist components. I cannot spot my error here.I have put the relevant components below.
Thank for your time in advance.
Leo

Coinlist

```
import Coins from './Coins';

export default function CoinList({filteredCoins}) {
  return (
      console.log(filteredCoins),
      filteredCoins.map(coin => {
        return (
          <Coins
            key={coin.id}
            name={coin.name}
            id={coin.id}
            price={coin.current_price}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            marketcap={coin.total_volume}
            volume={coin.market_cap}
            image={coin.image}
            priceChange={coin.price_change_percentage_24h}
          />
        );
      }))
  )}
```

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'
import Header from '../components/Header';
import CoinList from '../components/CoinList';

export default function Home({filteredCoins}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <CoinList filteredCoins={filteredCoins}/>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/
    markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_
    desc&per_page=50&page=1&sparkline=false`);

  const filteredCoins = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      filteredCoins
    }
  };
};
```

Coins

```
function Coins ({name}) {
    return (
        <h1>{name}</h1>
    );
}

export default Coins;
```

Comment: When you logged filteredCoins, are you getting any result? Does it print null and then the data, or is it just null.

Answer (score 0):

your fix is `props.filteredCoins.filteredCoins.map(coin => {`
can you try this, directly don't try to wrap it around the object,

```
  return {
    props: {
      filteredCoins
    }
  };
```

or else use it like, as you wrapped it inside `props` of `filteredCoins` of `filteredCoins`,

```
  //console.log(filteredCoins),
  //props.filteredCoins.filteredCoins.map(coin => {
```

so below is simple approach avoids wrapping of array into `{}` object,

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/
    markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_
    desc&per_page=50&page=1&sparkline=false`);

  const filteredCoins = await res.json();

  return filteredCoins;
};
```

this is what you have done,
[image]

Comment: Thanks @AshishKamble. I have tried both version but none works

Comment: `console.log(filteredCoins)` is it logging data on console?

Comment: no it doesn't. nothing get logs on the console

Comment: that means you are not getting data to map on it, man you are not calling that function `getServerSideProps `, how you passing `Home({filteredCoins})` to home